# OpenGL - Drawing A Clown Arm (3D oval shape)

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to create a clown using openGL. my only problem is what shape should i be using to create its arm?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw an usual sphere and transform it to oval via scaling by one axis?